# Declare ENTITY defining nbsp as the string "&nbsp;"

Tags: java, html, xml, xslt

I have a HTML document I need to transform by XSL. 
The HTML document includes usage of `&nbsp;`
i.e.,

```
ation.</span>&nbsp;</p><br/>All ...
```

Firstly I had troubles because   was not defined. 
So I defined it:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
<!DOCTYPE html [
    <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
"]>
```

I did so by prepending that code to the HTML string before sending it to the transformation. After the transformation, the ENTITY declaration was conveniently gone, and, yes, great, the transformation actually succeeded.

However! Because nbsp was defined as a space, the generated HTML/XML saw the strings `"&nbsp;"` actually replaced by a space character.

That is not what I want. I need that part of the result not to differ from the source.

So, I tried redefining the nbsp, like so:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
<!DOCTYPE html [
    <!ENTITY nbsp "&amp;nbsp;">
"]>
```

However, now instead of a space in my result, I see the characters `"&amp;nbsp;"`

If I try this:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
<!DOCTYPE html [
    <!ENTITY nbsp "&nbsp;">
"]>
```

I get a recursive declaration exception.

How do I then include the special character '&' in the definition ?

p.s., this transformation i'm running in Java 8, default engines (I guess that is xalan?).

Thanks all!

Here below is a short example of how to reproduce. Sorry for not providing it earlier.

---

```
package com.astraia.app.mainframe;

import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class ShortExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        StringBuffer htmlMain = new StringBuffer(500);
        htmlMain    .append("<html><head></head>")
                    .append("   <body>)")
                    .append("       <p data-tags=\"personal\"><strong>name: Nerea Morry,  Id: 5678</strong><br/></p>")
                    .append("       <p><span>some text</span>&nbsp;</p><br/>some more text")
                    .append("   </body>")
                    .append("</html>");

        StringBuffer xsl = new StringBuffer(500);
        xsl .append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>")
            .append("<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\" version=\"1.0\">")
            .append("   <xsl:output method=\"xml\" version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" omit-xml-declaration=\"yes\" />")
            .append("   <xsl:template match=\"node()|@*\" >")
            .append("       <!-- Copy all nodes -->")
            .append("       <xsl:copy>")
            .append("             <xsl:apply-templates select=\"node()|@*\" />")
            .append("       </xsl:copy>")
            .append("   </xsl:template>")
            .append("   <!-- Anonymize all text within tags indicated as personal -->")
            .append("   <xsl:template match=\"*[@data-tags = 'personal' ]//text()[normalize-space(.) != '']\">ANONYMIZED TEXT</xsl:template>")
            .append("   </xsl:stylesheet>");

        String plainHtml = htmlMain.toString();
        String transformation = xsl.toString();

        // results in &nbsp being replaced by a space
        printResult("results in &nbsp being replaced by a space", plainHtml,"&#160;", transformation);
        // results in seemingly non-replaced escape code &amp;
        printResult("results in seemingly non-replaced escape code &amp;", plainHtml,"&amp;nbsp", transformation);
        // results in recursion exception
        printResult("results in recursion exception", plainHtml,"&nbsp;", transformation);
        // also results in recursion exception
        printResult("also results in recursion exception", plainHtml,"&#038;nbsp;", transformation);

        // but what will result in:
        // <html><head/>    <body>)     <p data-tags="personal"><strong>ANONYMIZED TEXT</strong><br/></p>       <p><span>some text</span>&nbsp</p><br/>some more text   </body></html>
        // ?
    }

    public static void printResult(String message, String plainHtml, String definition, String transformation) {
        System.out.print(message);
        System.out.println(performTransformation(plainHtml,definition, transformation));
        System.out.println("\n-----");
    }

    public static String performTransformation(String plainHtml, String definition, String transformation)
    {
        String retval = null;

        try {
            StringWriter result = new StringWriter();
            StringBuffer header = new StringBuffer(100);
            header  .append("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>")
                    .append("<!DOCTYPE html [")
                    .append("    <!ENTITY nbsp REPLACE_ME>")
                    .append("]>\n");

            String headerText = header.toString().replace("REPLACE_ME", "\"" + definition + "\"");
            String wholeText = new StringBuffer(headerText).append(plainHtml).toString();

            TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Source xslt = new StreamSource(new StringReader(transformation));
            Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
            Source text = new StreamSource(new StringReader(wholeText));
            transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(result));
            retval = result.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return retval;
    }
}
```

---

Here is the output from my run of my little sample app:

```
results in &nbsp being replaced by a space<html><head/> <body>)     <p data-tags="personal"><strong>ANONYMIZED TEXT</strong><br/></p>       <p><span>some text</span> </p><br/>some more text   </body></html>

-----
results in seemingly non-replaced escape code &amp;<html><head/>    <body>)     <p data-tags="personal"><strong>ANONYMIZED TEXT</strong><br/></p>       <p><span>some text</span>&amp;nbsp</p><br/>some more text   </body></html>

-----
results in recursion exceptionjavax.xml.transform.TransformerException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Recursive entity reference "nbsp". (Reference path: nbsp -> nbsp -> nbsp),
null
ERROR:  'Recursive entity reference "nbsp". (Reference path: nbsp -> nbsp -> nbsp),'
-----
ERROR:  'com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Recursive entity reference "nbsp". (Reference path: nbsp -> nbsp -> nbsp),'

also results in recursion exceptionERROR:  'Recursive entity reference "nbsp". (Reference path: nbsp -> nbsp -> nbsp),'
ERROR:  'com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Recursive entity reference "nbsp". (Reference path: nbsp -> nbsp -> nbsp),'
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Recursive entity reference "nbsp". (Reference path: nbsp -> nbsp -> nbsp),
null

-----
```

The difference between the 4 tries being:

```
</span> </p><br/>some more text

</span>&amp;nbsp</p><br/>some more text

exception

exception
```

Comment: "*Because nbsp was defined as a space*" You show `nbsp` defined not as a space, but as a non-breaking space - and the transformation should preserve it (unless you did something to translate it to a space explicitly). Please post a **reproducible** example - see: [mcve]

Comment: What version of XSLT are you using and what processor are you using to process it?

Comment: @michael.hor257k   - yes, sorry, I have updated my post now with what I hope is a short enough and minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @DanielHaley  XSLT 1.0 , using the default processor in Java 8

Comment: Try changing the output method to `html`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k  Ah! In fact, that did fix the problem. The first usage then gives me what I want. Unfortunately it did introduce another problem (automatically introducing line breaks and a META tag I never asked for... but guess I'll (hopefully) be able to sort that out. thanks! I'll report back once I've finalized!

Comment: There is another option - I have posted an answer detailing both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have two options here:

1. Change the output method to `html`;
   This will output any non-breaking space as `&nbsp;`
2. Change the output encoding to `ASCII`;
   This will output any non-breaking space as `&#160;`

---

**Note**: If you leave the output method as `xml` and the encoding as `UTF-8`, the serialized result should still include an *unescaped* non-breaking space. There might be something else in your processing chain that prevents that from happening - or perhaps you are mistaking the character for a regular space (after all, they are rendered the same in most cases).